# How to create reusable UI control using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, sapui5

I would like to know if there is a way of creating resuable UI controls(e.g table,list,different layout etc) using JavaScript instead of using HTML directly.
I have seen similar controls in SAP UI5 where you can create objects of different UI controls with mostly using JavaScript and HTML DOM creation is handled by the respective
renderer.

What would be your advice on how to create similar controls from scratch using JavaScript and jQuery which also supports binding?

Is there any other library or framework available similar to SAP UI5 providing rich set of UI controls(e.g table,list etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into javascript templating. See mustache.js for one example.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
   {{#elements}}
      <div id="{{id}}">
         {{content}}
      </div>
   {{/elements}}
</script>
```

And your JavaScript:

```
var view = {
   "elements": 
    [
       {
          id: "one",
          content: "Lorem ipsum dolor"
       },
       {
          id: "two",
          content: "Sit amet consectetur"
       }
    ]
}

var template = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
var output = Mustache.render(template, view);
console.log(output);
logs:

<div id="one">
   Lorem ipsum dolor
</div>
<div id="two">
   Sit amet consectetur
</div>
```

You can loop through objects, evaluate functions and insert them as text.

If you use angularJS you can create a reusable html piece by making a separate html file with your component then calling it into your page as an element.

```
app.directive("elementName", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "/Path/To/Html.file"
  };
});
```

Then in every html page you want to use this component you just do the following:

```
<element-name></element-name>
```